# Is it possible/advisable to upgrade a DD-WRT router remotely?

Tags: router

I have two DD-WRT routers in different locations.  One of them is running the VPN version of the firmware, and the other is running the standard version.  I am on location with the VPN one, and I want to upgrade the other one to run the VPN firmware so I can wire them together.  Is this possible or advisable?  Of course, I don't want to lose the settings on the remote one, since then I would lose my remote access (currently through SSH) and not be able to configure it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't rule out the possibility of doing it but I can make some points against it.

- The recommended process (strongly reiterated by DD-WRT) involves a series of 'hard' resets that involve power cycling while holding down the **physical reset** button on the router. Tricky to do remotely :)
- Saved settings for one version of the firmware should **NEVER** be used with a different version.

Answer (score 2):

It's *never* advisable to upgrade any router remotely, unless you have separate out-of-band access to it.

I base that recommendation on a decade of running the core networks for an ISP (in a previous job)

Answer (score 0):

I can say from personal experience that I have nearly bricked my router trying to upgrade DD-WRT over the web interface via remote connections. I would strongly recommend being physically connected to the router and having physical access.

The hard reset procedure that is officially recommended also comes in handy if anything goes wrong.